# Getting A new session could not be created

Tags: java, android, appium, appium-android

Can anyone help me out I am new to Android testing with Appium , I am trying to open app in AVD the app getting installed but then m getting Error "A new Session could not be created.(Original error: Command failed: )","killed":false,"code":1,"signal":null,"origValue":"Command failed: "},"sessionId":null}

Thanks for the help in advance

tried with just giving capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", ".MainActivity");

```
'''



File classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        File appDir = new File(classpathRoot, "/Apps/src/");
        File app = new File(appDir, "ChatApp-release.apk");

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "emulator-5554");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.1.1");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.aaa.charla");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.aaa.xxx.MainActivity");

        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("https://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        driver.quit();
```

Following are the Debug log:

> info: Console LogLevel: debug
>   info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"D:\AndroidNew\Yrreport\YrReport\RemoteSystemsTempFiles\Appium\apk\ChatApp-master-0.9.35.1195-release.apk","appPackage":"com.odysseyinc.charla","appActivity":"com.odyssey.chatapp.MainActivity","newCommandTimeout":"10000","platformName":"Android","version":"7.1.1","deviceName":"emulator-5554"}}
>   info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_162)
>   info: [debug] The following desired capabilities were provided, but not recognized by appium. They will be passed on to any other services running on this server. : version
>   info: [debug] Using local app from desired caps: D:\AndroidNew\Yrreport\YrReport\RemoteSystemsTempFiles\Appium\apk\ChatApp-master-0.9.35.1195-release.apk
>   info: [debug] Creating new appium session 0d25aeac-d055-449f-af84-b6d314d9b4a5
>   info: Starting android appium
>   info: [debug] Getting Java version
>   info: Java version is: 1.8.0_162
>   info: [debug] Checking whether adb is present
>   info: [debug] Using adb from C:\Users\unmesh.ghatbandhe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
>   info: [debug] Set chromedriver binary as: C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\chromedriver\windows\chromedriver.exe
>   info: [debug] Using fast reset? true
>   info: [debug] Preparing device for session
>   info: [debug] Checking whether app is actually present
>   info: Retrieving device
>   info: [debug] Trying to find a connected android device
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\unmesh.ghatbandhe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
>   info: [debug] 1 device(s) connected
>   info: Found device emulator-5554
>   info: [debug] Setting device id to emulator-5554
>   info: [debug] Waiting for device to be ready and to respond to shell commands (timeout = 5)
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\unmesh.ghatbandhe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 wait-for-device
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\unmesh.ghatbandhe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "echo 'ready'"
>   info: [debug] Starting logcat capture
>   info: [debug] Getting device API level
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\unmesh.ghatbandhe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
>   info: [debug] Device is at API Level 25
>   info: Device API level is: 25
>   info: [debug] Extracting strings for language: default
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\unmesh.ghatbandhe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "getprop persist.sys.language"
>   info: [debug] Current device persist.sys.language: 
>   info: [debug] java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\appium_apk_tools.jar" "stringsFromApk" "D:\AndroidNew\Yrreport\YrReport\RemoteSystemsTempFiles\Appium\apk\ChatApp-master-0.9.35.1195-release.apk" "C:\Users\UNMESH~1.GHA\AppData\Local\Temp\com.odysseyinc.charla" 
>   info: [debug] Reading strings from converted strings.json
>   info: [debug] Setting language to default
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\unmesh.ghatbandhe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 push "C:\Users\UNMESH~1.GHA\AppData\Local\Temp\com.odysseyinc.charla\strings.json" /data/local/tmp
>   info: [debug] Checking whether aapt is present
>   info: [debug] Using aapt from C:\Users\unmesh.ghatbandhe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\aapt.exe
>   info: [debug] Retrieving process from manifest.
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\unmesh.ghatbandhe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\aapt.exe dump xmltree D:\AndroidNew\Yrreport\YrReport\RemoteSystemsTempFiles\Appium\apk\ChatApp-master-0.9.35.1195-release.apk AndroidManifest.xml
>   info: [debug] Set app process to: com.odysseyinc.charla
>   info: [debug] Not uninstalling app since server not started with --full-reset
>   info: [debug] Checking app cert for D:\AndroidNew\Yrreport\YrReport\RemoteSystemsTempFiles\Appium\apk\ChatApp-master-0.9.35.1195-release.apk.
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\verify.jar" D:\AndroidNew\Yrreport\YrReport\RemoteSystemsTempFiles\Appium\apk\ChatApp-master-0.9.35.1195-release.apk
>   info: [debug] App already signed.
>   info: [debug] Zip-aligning D:\AndroidNew\Yrreport\YrReport\RemoteSystemsTempFiles\Appium\apk\ChatApp-master-0.9.35.1195-release.apk
>   info: [debug] Checking whether zipalign is present
>   info: [debug] Using zipalign from C:\Users\unmesh.ghatbandhe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\zipalign.exe
>   info: [debug] Zip-aligning apk.
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\unmesh.ghatbandhe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\zipalign.exe -f 4 D:\AndroidNew\Yrreport\YrReport\RemoteSystemsTempFiles\Appium\apk\ChatApp-master-0.9.35.1195-release.apk C:\Users\UNMESH~1.GHA\AppData\Local\Temp\119427-15556-1rmbgw9\appium.tmp
>   info: [debug] MD5 for app is f3d7efc8b197792c3d0529a48dc92ff2
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\unmesh.ghatbandhe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "ls /data/local/tmp/f3d7efc8b197792c3d0529a48dc92ff2.apk"
>   info: [debug] Getting install status for com.odysseyinc.charla
>   info: [debug] Getting device API level
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\unmesh.ghatbandhe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
>   info: [debug] Device is at API Level 25
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\unmesh.ghatbandhe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "pm list packages -3 com.odysseyinc.charla"
>   info: [debug] App is installed
>   info: App is already installed, resetting app
>   info: [debug] Running fast reset (stop and clear)
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\unmesh.ghatbandhe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "am force-stop com.odysseyinc.charla"
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\unmesh.ghatbandhe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell "pm clear com.odysseyinc.charla"
>   info: [debug] Forwarding system:4724 to device:4724
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\unmesh.ghatbandhe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 forward tcp:4724 tcp:4724
>   info: [debug] Pushing appium bootstrap to device...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\unmesh.ghatbandhe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 push "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\android_bootstrap\AppiumBootstrap.jar" /data/local/tmp/
>   info: [debug] Pushing settings apk to device...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\unmesh.ghatbandhe\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk"
>   info: [debug] Stopping logcat capture
>   info: [debug] Logcat terminated with code null, signal SIGTERM
>   info: [debug] Sent shutdown command, waiting for UiAutomator to stop...
>   warn: UiAutomator did not shut down fast enough, calling it gone
>   error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Command failed: adb: failed to install C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install io.appium.settings without first uninstalling.]
>
> info: [debug] Cleaning up android objects
>   info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
>   info: [debug] Error: Command failed: adb: failed to install C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install io.appium.settings without first uninstalling.]
>
> ```
> at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:637:15)
> at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
> at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
> at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
> ```
>
> info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Command failed: adb: failed to install C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install io.appium.settings without first uninstalling.]\r\n)","killed":false,"code":1,"signal":null,"origValue":"Command failed: adb: failed to install C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install io.appium.settings without first uninstalling.]\r\n"},"sessionId":null}
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 32039.992 ms - 664

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have upgraded the Appuim 1.4 to 1.9 and started working as Expected .

Answer (score 0):

You need to share the full appium logs in order to know the reason for that.
[After checking the logs]
That's a known issue for that specific Android image as it installs 2 versions of appium settings app and unlock app. What you can do is either change the android image you are testing against or uninstall those 2 apps before starting your script.

You can uninstall them manually by starting the emulator GUI and do that with the mouse or through the below commands:

```
adb -s device_serial uninstall io.appium.settings
adb -s device_serial uninstall io.appium.unlock
```

Also, you can add those commands in your code if you really have to execute the tests on android 7 devices as below:

```
String androidVersion=executeCommand("adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release");
if(androidVersion.contains("7"))
{
    //uninstall appium settings app
    cmd="adb uninstall  io.appium.settings";
    executeCommand(cmd);

    //uninstall appium unlock app
    cmd="adb uninstall  io.appium.unlock";
    executeCommand(cmd);
}
```

Comment: I have added the Full appium Logs  can you please check

Comment: Well! It's not a answer!

Comment: You can tell to him in comment

Comment: No require to give answer to tell add your full appium!

Comment: @DineshShingadiya I can't comment yet on posts. :)

Comment: Better for you to earn `comment-privilege`

Comment: @Sharaf I have tried 
`adb -s device_serial uninstall io.appium.settings`
`adb -s device_serial uninstall io.appium.unlock`

But I am getting 
`info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Command failed: )","killed":false,"code":1,"signal":null,"origValue":"Command failed: "},"sessionId":null}
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 35894.737 ms - 192 
`

Comment: You need to replace the device_serial with your device serial that is displayed when you type adb devices

Comment: @Sharaf yes I did that and after I executed the test and getting this error

Comment: @UnmeshGhatbandhe Can you share your execution logs after running those commands from cmd?

Comment: > info: [debug] Error: Command failed: 
>     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:637:15)
>     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
>     at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
>     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
> info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Command failed: )","killed":false,"code":1,"signal":null,"origValue":"Command failed: "},"sessionId":null}
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 35894.737 ms - 192

Comment: @Sharaf Thanks its working now I have upgraded the Appuim 1.4 to 1.9 and started working as Expected

Comment: @UnmeshGhatbandhe Great. You can also upgrade to the latest version 1.13.0 which has more features and this issue will be fixed in it as well. Please, mark the answer, it helps a lot. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Sharaf Thanks :) , Will Mark the the Answer